# How to cunstruct PHP and SQL statement compact

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, bind

How can i construct this if and if else clause easier (compact)?
On my first SQL statement the value "ticket" is not set by bind parameter, because it doesnt work. I dont know why. On the rest of SQL statements binding paramters works great.

It is simple what i want. I will save PIC names in DB, if this column name is empty, if not go to the next column name.... and so on

```
        if (empty($file->error)) {
    /* get values from db for pic rows */
        $sql = 'SELECT bild1, bild2, bild3, bild4, bild5, bild6 FROM '.$this->options['db_table'].' WHERE `ticket`=?';
        $result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    /* save pic names 1-6 to db */ 
        if (empty($row["bild1"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild1`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild1 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        elseif (empty($row["bild2"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild2`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild2 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        elseif (empty($row["bild3"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild3`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild3 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        elseif (empty($row["bild4"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild4`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild4 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        elseif (empty($row["bild5"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild5`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild5 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        elseif (empty($row["bild6"])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild6`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild6 IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();
        }
        // $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you have tons of these, a loop wouldn't hurt if that's what you're getting at.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for-loop to loop over all the bild-numbers, and break when one matched:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    if (empty($row["bild".$i])) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` SET `bild'.$i.'`=? WHERE `ticket`=? AND bild'.$i.' IS NULL';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $this->options['ticket']);
        $query->execute();

        // Break out of the loop, so no other bildx whill be tried
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great... i anderstand it how it works... but i have an issue on my first SQL statement to check if my bild1, bild2, ... are empty or not.

Comment: This works for me but the ticket value is not dynamicly added: 
`code`
/* get values from db for pic rows */
        $sql = 'SELECT bild1, bild2, bild3, bild4, bild5, bild6 FROM '.$this->options['db_table'].' WHERE `ticket`=AABC5AS';
        $result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();`code`

Comment: You have a question-mark in your query (not above, but in your original question), but you don't bind a parameter to it (`$query->bind_param(..)`)

Comment: Yes you right... i tried something like the others statements who works great to bind param, but no luck. Like this:

Comment: [code] $sql = 'SELECT bild1, bild2, bild3, bild4, bild5, bild6 FROM '.$this->options['db_table'].' WHERE `ticket`=?';
         $result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
   $query->bind_param('s', $this->options['ticket']);
   $query->execute();
         $row = $result->fetch_assoc();[/code]

Comment: You are storing the prepared statement in `$result` but are calling `bind_param` on `$query`?

Comment: I renamed the calling on bind_param, but no luck. Looks like this:
<code>$sql = 'SELECT bild1, bild2, bild3, bild4, bild5, bild6 FROM '.$this->options['db_table'].' WHERE ticket=?'; 
$result = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
$result->bind_param('s', $this->options['ticket']); 
$result->execute(); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();</code>

Comment: Don't know your table-name, but maybe its because the other queries have backticks ` around the table and this one hasn't. Otherwise try debugging by adding a `echo 'Prepare: '.$this->db->error;` after your prepare, bind_param and execute-statements.

Comment: Backticks are not the problem! My table name is not the issue.... i think i do something wrong with this: $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Overlooked it the first time: `$dbresult = $result->get_result(); $row = $dbresult->fetch_assoc()` (maybe you should rename $result into $query to be more clear). Also check that `$row !== null`, it will be if that row isn't in the db.

Comment: My frind everything is right in my code but there is a issue with parsing my ticket value in the sql statement! parsing static -> Works parsing dynamicly ->DOESNT WORK!

This work: $sql = 'SELECT `bild1`, `bild2`, `bild3`, `bild4`, `bild5`, `bild6` FROM `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `ticket`=ABNFSD56gH';

THIS Doesnt WORK: $sql = 'SELECT `bild1`, `bild2`, `bild3`, `bild4`, `bild5`, `bild6` FROM `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `ticket`=`'.$this->options['ticket'].'`';